# I need help github and intelij idea

Tags: reactjs, github, intellij-idea

Your help is very necessary. I am creating react-project in intellij idea. When I want to commit files before pushing them to github, I can't see all the files with folders that were created. When I create a branch, it is visible on github, but files and folders are NOT pushed and they are not visible. How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much)

This is my files and folders

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV0eI.png)

And here is what I get after committing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyj0e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your files are not confirmed or tracked. If you run git status in the Terminal you will see all files added or changed. So you need to add this files to git tracking and after to perform a commit. And finally, git push to upload your changes to Github.

In the UI simply mark the checkbox to add all files to the commit.

Comment: I know this when I create a project I see in the corner that there is a message where I can choose: “View files” and “Always add.” It shows all my project files, but even after I click "Add" I don't have those files, but there are thousands of unfamiliar files as in the picture. What could be the matter?